# MySQL Update is not executed as expected in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, for-loop

I am trying to read user rating in a table, and update their final user rating. Please see the below code.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host: prop.get('server.host'),
    user: prop.get("server.username"),
    password: prop.get("server.password"),
    port: prop.get("server.port"),
    database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.userRatingManager = async (event, context) => {

    const connection = await pool.getConnection();
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    connection.config.namedPlaceholders = true;


        try {
            await connection.beginTransaction();

            //Get the list of users
            const selectUserSql = "SELECT * FROM user";
            const [userData, userMeta] = await connection.query(selectUserSql);

            //Get the list of feedback for the selected user
            const feedBackSql = "SELECT * FROM job_feedback WHERE to_user = ?";

            for(let i = 0; i<userData.length; i++)
            {
                let userId = Number(userData[i].iduser);
                const [feedbackData, feedbackMeta] = await connection.query(feedBackSql, [userId]);

                if(feedbackData.length>0)
                {
                    let noOfFeedbacks = feedbackData.length;
                    let totalRating = 0;
                    let finalUserRating = 0;

                    console.log(feedbackData[0].to_user);

                    for(let feed=0; feed<feedbackData.length; feed++)
                    {
                        console.log( feedbackData[feed].feedback);
                        totalRating = totalRating+feedbackData[feed].rating;
                    }

                    finalUserRating = totalRating/noOfFeedbacks;
                    console.log("final rating: "+finalUserRating);

                    //Insert the final rating into the user commons
                    const updateRatingSql = "UPDATE user_common SET rating = ? WHERE iduser = ?";
                    const updateRatingResult = await connection.query(updateRatingSql, {finalUserRating, userId});
                    console.log("updated usrid: "+userId);

                    //Print the response
                    console.log(JSON.stringify({
                        updateRatingResult
                    }));

                }
            }

            //Commit and complete
            await connection.commit();

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            await connection.rollback();
            return errorCodes.save_failed;
            
        }
        finally{
            connection.release();
        }
};
```

This does everything right except updating the `user_common` table records. I can confirm the SQL syntax is right, because when I manually post it into MySQL Workbench and execute with the same data as below, it works.

Below is the output I get from the console print. You can clearly see that no record is updated at all.

```
2022-09-30T07:39:00.512Z        66fd22f4-63f7-4b36-9982-499393b4d316    INFO    29
2022-09-30T07:39:00.516Z        66fd22f4-63f7-4b36-9982-499393b4d316    INFO    A very good Buyer.
2022-09-30T07:39:00.517Z        66fd22f4-63f7-4b36-9982-499393b4d316    INFO    Amazing buyer
2022-09-30T07:39:00.518Z        66fd22f4-63f7-4b36-9982-499393b4d316    INFO    final rating: 5
2022-09-30T07:39:00.810Z        66fd22f4-63f7-4b36-9982-499393b4d316    INFO    updated usrid: 29
2022-09-30T07:39:00.811Z        66fd22f4-63f7-4b36-9982-499393b4d316    INFO    {"updateRatingResult":[{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"info":"Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0","serverStatus":3,"warningStatus":0,"changedRows":0},null]}
2022-09-30T07:39:15.518Z        66fd22f4-63f7-4b36-9982-499393b4d316    INFO    112
2022-09-30T07:39:15.519Z        66fd22f4-63f7-4b36-9982-499393b4d316    INFO    A very good seller. Nice
2022-09-30T07:39:15.519Z        66fd22f4-63f7-4b36-9982-499393b4d316    INFO    Excellent work
2022-09-30T07:39:15.523Z        66fd22f4-63f7-4b36-9982-499393b4d316    INFO    final rating: 4.5
2022-09-30T07:39:15.849Z        66fd22f4-63f7-4b36-9982-499393b4d316    INFO    updated usrid: 112
2022-09-30T07:39:15.850Z        66fd22f4-63f7-4b36-9982-499393b4d316    INFO    {"updateRatingResult":[{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"info":"Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0","serverStatus":3,"warningStatus":0,"changedRows":0},null]}
```

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Check this out.

```
const updateRatingResult = await connection.query(updateRatingSql, {finalUserRating, userId});
```

`{}` are for named parameters. Since I am not using named parameters what I should use is `[]`.